# MSBuild build fails when trying to use the "Get" task

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-automation

I'm in the midst of doing a test upgrade from TFS2010 to TFS2012. They're using the Upgrade Template to run an extensive set of custom MSBuild tasks to automate their build and deployment. The MSBuild projects were originally created for TFS2005, and were upgraded directly to TFS2010 at some point. The solutions they're building are mostly targeted at .NET 2.0, and they're still using VS2005 for most development.

So far, I've installed VS2005, VS2010, and TFS2012 with Update 1 (in that order), and upgraded their TFS2010 databases to TFS2012. The build controller lives on the same machine as the app tier and database, just because this is a "proof of concept" upgrade to identify any issues that will need to be addressed with the build process prior to the real upgrade.

When I run any of their MSBuild-based builds, I get the following error:

> C:\Builds\18\Web\ES-INTEGRATION-WebTest\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj (75):
>   An extension of type
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildDetail' must be
>   configured in order to run this workflow. 
>   C:\Builds\18\Web\ES-INTEGRATION-WebTest\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj (75):
>   The "Get" task failed unexpectedly.
>
> System.Activities.ValidationException: An extension of type
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildDetail' must be
>   configured in order to run this workflow.
>
> at
>   System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstanceExtensionCollection..ctor(Activity
>   workflowDefinition, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensionManager)
>
> at
>   System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager.CreateInstanceExtensions(Activity
>   workflowDefinition, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensionManager)
>
> at
>   System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.RegisterExtensionManager(WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager
>   extensionManager)
>
> at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.EnsureInitialized()
>
> at
>   System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.RunInstance(WorkflowApplication
>   instance)
>
> at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Invoke(Activity activity,
>   IDictionary`2 inputs, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions,
>   TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at System.Activities.WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(Activity workflow,
>   IDictionary`2 inputs, TimeSpan timeout,
>   WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.WorkflowTask.ExecuteInternal()
>
> at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()

I've gone through and pared the build down to a very small case that reproduces the issue. The complete .proj file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="DesktopBuild" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">

    <!-- Do not edit this -->
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\TeamBuild\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets" />
    <ProjectExtensions>
        <!--  DESCRIPTION
     The description is associated with a build type. Edit the value for making changes.
    -->
        <Description>Builds and Deploys the BE site to the integration environment</Description>
        <!--  BUILD MACHINE
     Name of the machine which will be used to build the solutions selected.
    -->
        <BuildMachine>[redacted]</BuildMachine>
    </ProjectExtensions>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!--  TEAM PROJECT
     The team project which will be built using this build type.
    -->
        <TeamProject>Web</TeamProject>
        <!--  BUILD DIRECTORY
     The directory on the build machine that will be used to build the
     selected solutions. The directory must be a local path on the build
     machine (e.g. c:\build).
    -->
        <BuildDirectoryPath>c:\build</BuildDirectoryPath>
        <!--  DROP LOCATION
      The location to drop (copy) the built binaries and the log files after
     the build is complete. This location has to be a valid UNC path of the
     form \\Server\Share. The build machine service account and application
     tier account need to have read write permission on this share.
    -->
        <DropLocation>\\[redacted]\BuildDrop</DropLocation>
        <!--  TESTING
     Set this flag to enable/disable running tests as a post build step.
    -->
        <RunTest>True</RunTest>
        <!--  WorkItemFieldValues
      Add/edit key value pairs to set values for fields in the work item created
      during the build process. Please make sure the field names are valid 
      for the work item type being used.
    -->
        <WorkItemFieldValues>Symptom=build break;Steps To Reproduce=Start the build using Team Build</WorkItemFieldValues>
        <!--  CODE ANALYSIS
       To change CodeAnalysis behavior edit this value. Valid values for this
       can be Default,Always or Never.

     Default - To perform code analysis as per the individual project settings
     Always  - To always perform code analysis irrespective of project settings
     Never   - To never perform code analysis irrespective of project settings
     -->
        <RunCodeAnalysis>Default</RunCodeAnalysis>
        <!--  UPDATE ASSOCIATED WORK ITEMS
     Set this flag to enable/disable updating associated workitems on a successful build
    -->
        <UpdateAssociatedWorkItems>false</UpdateAssociatedWorkItems>
        <!-- Title for the work item created on build failure -->
        <WorkItemTitle>Build failure in build:</WorkItemTitle>
        <!-- Description for the work item created on build failure -->
        <DescriptionText>This work item was created by Team Build on a build failure.</DescriptionText>
        <!-- Text pointing to log file location on build failure -->
        <BuildlogText>The build log file is at:</BuildlogText>
        <!-- Text pointing to error/warnings file location on build failure -->
        <ErrorWarningLogText>The errors/warnings log file is at:</ErrorWarningLogText>
    </PropertyGroup>



    <PropertyGroup>
        <SourceBranchPath>Main</SourceBranchPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Does some basic validation of the environment before the build starts -->
  <Target Name="PreBuildValidations" >
    <Get FileSpec="$/Web/$(SourceBranchPath)/BuildFiles/Tools/PSExec.exe" Workspace="$(WorkspaceName)" Recursive="false" Force="true" TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"/>
  </Target>

    <Target Name="BeforeGet">
        <CallTarget Targets="PreBuildValidations" />
    </Target>


</Project>
```

Comment: What's the value of `ProjectFileVersion` in your tfsbuild.proj?

Comment: `ProjectFileVersion` is 4.

Comment: The MSBuild platform *is* set to `x86`.

Comment: Does your workspace contain the file spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently, the `BuildUri` parameter is required for the `Get` task. I added `BuildUri="$(BuildURI)"` and all is well.

Answer (score -1):

Your build is failing on the "[Get Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa721740%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)" in your msbuild script. You are only pulling down one file which is an .exe file in the BeforeGet target. In order to build a project you need a project file.

It looks like the error may be because you missing a parameter or passing in an invalid parameter in the Get task.

Why the need for a prebuildvalidation step when the build can just pull the file down from the build definition workspace?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of *where* it's failing. I've confirmed that the parameters being passed to the `Get` task are valid. Keep in mind, this works perfectly against a TFS2010 environment. As to the "Why does it do the things that it does," this was created in ages long past by others. I have no insight into why they made the decisions that they did. After the TFS2012 upgrade, the intention is to upgrade the entire build process to something a bit more modern.

Comment: Do you get the error if you run msbuild from the command line on your local box? This will ensure that the Get task has the correct parameters.

Comment: Why the down-vote when the solution was an invalid parameter? I stated this in the answer as the possible problem. I also referenced the GetTask MSDN page which shows the needed parameters and example.